# MongoDB aggregation framework approach to a multi-doc query

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am looking into the best way to organize filtering. I have the following document format:

```
{
 _id: "info",
 ids: ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
}

{
 _id: "id1",
 value: 5
}

{
 _id: "id2",
 value: 1
}

{
 _id: "id3",
 value: 5
}
```

I need to make the following query: get all documents by id from doc "info" and then filter them out by value 5. So, that result would be something like:

```
{
 _id: "id1",
 value: 5
}

{
 _id: "id3",
 value: 5
}
```

I suppose I need to do unwind on ids, but how do I then select all documents that match those values? Or maybe I should just use $in operator somehow to grab all documents and after that do filtering?

Any help is aprpeciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only MongoDB shell/script, I would do it like this:

```
db.ids.find({ _id: { $in: db.ids.findOne({ _id: "info" }).ids }, value: 5 })
```

You also have worse versions using:

- or the [`eval` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval):

  ```
  db.runCommand({
      eval: function(value) {
          var ids = db.ids.findOne({ _id: "info" }).ids;
          return db.ids.find({ _id: { $in: ids }, value: value }).toArray();
      },
      args: [5]
  })
  ```
- or the [`$where` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where) (low performance because you execute one find for each candidate result with `value` 5):

  ```
  db.ids.find({
      value: 5,
      $where: "db.ids.findOne({ _id: 'info', ids: this._id })"
  })
  ```

But if you are trying to run the queries through a MongoDb driver, the story might be different.

Comment: Hi, no this is going to be called from a language, not from shell. I am going to do other operations, such as doing sums of values together, etc. In your case this doesn't seem to be possible, because this is all just 2 nested queries with $in operator. In my case this can be huge, up to hundred thousand of documents search from a total list of millions :) I suppose in this case it's either aggregation framework or map\reduce.

Comment: yes, map reduce is powerful. I did not find a map-reduce solution for your example.